# Using CONTAINS with variables sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, contains

Ok so I am trying to reference one variable with another in SQL.

X= a,b,c,d    (x is a string variable with a list of things in it)

Y= b          ( Y is a string variable that may or may not have a vaue that appears in X)

I tried this:

```
Case when Y in (X) then 1 else 0 end as aa
```

But it doesnt work since it looks for exact matches between X and Y

also tried this:

```
where contains(X,@Y)
```

but i cant create Y globally since it is a variable that changes in each row of the table.( x also changes)

A solution in SAS would also be useful.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe `like` will help

```
select 
  *
from
  t
where
  X like ('%'+Y+'%')
```

or

```
select 
  case when (X like ('%'+Y+'%')) then 1 else 0 end
from
  t
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfc9a/2)

Comment: watch out for this problem:  you are looking for `123` and your lists is `222,1234,444` this query will find it incorrectly.

Comment: @KM. You are right, a workaround would be to search for `123,`  depends on the data.

Answer (score 0):

In SAS I would use the INDEX function, either in a data step or proc sql.  This returns the position within the string in which it finds the character(s), or zero if there is no match.  Therefore a test if the value returned is greater than zero will result in a binary 1:0 output.  You need to use the compress function with the variable containing the search characters as SAS pads the value with blanks.

Data step solution :

```
aa=index(x,compress(y))>0;
```

Proc Sql solution :

```
index(x,compress(y))>0 as aa
```